# I am getting this error and my I cant solve it the error is :-( _this.state.tokenFarm.methods.stakeTokens is not a function ) please help me ASAP

Tags: solidity

```
  stakeTokens = (amount) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    this.state.daiToken.methods.approve(this.state.tokenFarm.options.address, amount).send({ from: this.state.account })
      .on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
        this.state.tokenFarm.methods.stakeTokens(amount).send({ from: this.state.account })
          .on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
            this.setState({ loading: false })
          })
      })
  }
```

Comment: This is really an incomplete question. Please add more details. Like the contract initialization etc.